# How to define transaction.atomic in a Django class-based view?

Tags: django

I want the `post` method in the class-based view to be atomic. I have defined the class so:

```
class AcceptWith(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(my_test))
    @method_decorator(transaction.atomic)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AcceptWith, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

1. Is this correct?
2. Can I make only the post method atomic?

Comment: Why do you need 'dispatch' to be atomic?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that you're defining your own method to handle the `POST`, just apply the `transaction.atomic` decorator directly to that method.

```
class AcceptWith(View):
    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your code here will be executed atomically
```

Comment: Wow. And I just create my post handler normally? Can I use this for ANY django decorators? Could you introduce me to the mechanism?

Comment: since it just function https://github.com/django/django/blob/059f5d17c5fe92d6b4c5d189020ea59e9bed4472/django/db/transaction.py#L296 you should wrap it in method decorator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.method_decorator

Comment: @madzohan: That isn't necessary. `method_decorator` is needed for decorators that are designed to return a function without `self` in the argument signature. `transaction.atomic` [doesn't care about](https://github.com/django/django/blob/059f5d17c5fe92d6b4c5d189020ea59e9bed4472/django/db/transaction.py#L290) the function signature at all. Note [this example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L93) from the admin code.

Comment: No need to decorate `dispatch`? What am I missing here?

Comment: @rtindru: The OP wrote "Can I make only the post method atomic?" So you can't decorate `dispatch()`.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I mean generally: I was under the impression that decorators don't work straight on `post` and `get` for CBV, you are forced to decorate `dispatch`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @rtindru: The reason you normally apply decorators to `dispatch()` is 1) it serves as a common entry point for all class-based views for all HTTP request methods; and 2) its argument signature matches that of the function-based views (other than `self`, which is dealt with by using `method_decorator`), allowing you to use the same decorators (e.g. `login_required`). Outside of those considerations, which don't apply here, decorators work just as you'd expect on any method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not wrap whole method, also you may want custom handler execute after rollback

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    try: 
        with transaction.atomic(): 
            pass  # CRUD operations 
    except IntegrityError: 
        handle_exception()  # this will run after rollback
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/